# Catch and Modify XHR requests from Facebook with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

Trying to catch and modify XHR requests from Facebook.com. The exact request URL is

https://www.facebook.com/ajax/composerx/attachment/link/scraper/?scrape_url={A URL GOES HERE}.

Is this possible with a chrome extension? Searched everywhere to no avail.

Comment: It is possible using the [`webRequest`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) API.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onCompleted

If you want to modify what is getting sent out, then I think what you'll want is onBeforeRequest handler to be registered.